# Angular 2 - Return HttpClient JSON to Object

Tags: angular

I start with Angular2 and need some help.

When I request a JSON from HTTP its returns how I expected, but I cant convert an Observable to my especific Object.

The problem is convert the return of method getHttpRequest to a object AlarmStatus

HTML:

```
   DATE {{alarmStatus.updateDate}}
```

CLASS:

```
export class AlarmStatus {
  updateDate: string;

  fromJSON(obj: any) {
    this.updateDate = obj.updateDate;

    return this;
  }
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularCompilerOptions } from '@angular/compiler-cli';

import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

import { AlarmStatus } from '../alarmStatus';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  alarmStatus: AlarmStatus;

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('service: ', this.dashboardService.getHttpRequest());
  }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { AlarmStatus } from '../alarmStatus';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {

  private _url = 'http://localhost/teste.php?action=getData';

  alarmStatus: AlarmStatus;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getHttpRequest(): Observable<AlarmStatus> {
       return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((res: Response) => res )
      .subscribe((json: Object) => {
        this.alarmStatus = new AlarmStatus().fromJSON(json);
      });

  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subscribe in your component. Your code will look like this:

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularCompilerOptions } from '@angular/compiler-cli';

import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

import { AlarmStatus } from '../alarmStatus';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  alarmStatus: AlarmStatus;

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getHttpRequest().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
  }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { AlarmStatus } from '../alarmStatus';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {

  private _url = 'http://localhost/teste.php?action=getData';

  alarmStatus: AlarmStatus;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getHttpRequest(): Observable<AlarmStatus> {
       return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((res: Response) => new AlarmStatus().fromJSON(res); )


  }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: 1 more advise => Never subscribe observable in service. It's bad practice. Always try to subscribe in your component and never forget to unsubscribe observable. Observable prone to memory leakage and this will slow down browser of user.